# Generic values in F# modules?

Tags: f#

Consider a generic container like:

```ml
type Foo<'t> = 
  {
    Foo : 't
  }
```

This generic function works OK:

```ml
module Foo = 
  
  let inline emptyFoo () = 
    {
      Foo = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    }
```

But this value does not:

```ml
module Foo = 
  
  let emptyFoo = 
    {
      Foo = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    }
```

This is because the compiler infers `emptyFoo` to have type `Foo<obj>`.

However, the standard library has generic values like `List.empty`, so how is that achieved there?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make it explicitly generic.

`List.empty` is implemented like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L117-117):

```
let empty<'T> = ([ ] : 'T list)
```

Comment: Be aware that this approach have won't work for arbitrary value. `List.empty` is handled in a special way by compiler - it's static method that returns `FSharpList<T>.Empty` which is singleton. But if you create your own module, it will be compiled to static method that evaluates body on every access. For example `module RA = let empty<'a> = ResizeArray<'a>()` will create new instance of `ResizeArray` on each access and `RA.empty = RA.empty` will return false

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a List by yourself, with an empty. It looks like this.

```
type L<'a> =
    | Null
    | Cons of 'a * L<'a>

module L =
    let empty = Null

let xs = Cons(1,  Cons(2,  L.empty))
let ys = Cons(1.0,Cons(2.0,L.empty))
```

So, why does `L.empty` in this case works in a generic way? Because the value `Null` has no special value attached to it. You could say, it is compatible with every other generic.

In your Record on the other hand, you always must produce a value. `LanguagePrimitive.GenericZero` is not some Generic value. It help so to resolve to a special zero value, and this value is determined by the other code you write.

For example

```
let x = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
```

is also `obj`

```
let x = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero + 1
```

will be `int`. And

```
let x = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero + 1.0
```

will be `float`. So in some case you can think of `GenericZero` just as a placeholder for zero for the special type you need, but the code needs to determine at this point, which type you want.

You could change your type, with an option to provide a real empty.

```
type Foo<'t> = {
    Foo: 't option
}

module Foo =
    let empty = { Foo = None }

let x = Foo.empty                  // Foo<'a>
let y = { x with Foo = Some 1   }  // Foo<int>
let z = { x with Foo = Some 1.0 }  // Foo<float>
```

---

### Zero Member

Maybe you want a Zero Member on some types. For example

```
type Vector3 = {X:float; Y:float; Z:float} with
    static member create x y z = {X=x; Y=y; Z=z}
    static member (+) (a,b)    = Vector3.create (a.X + b.X) (a.Y + b.Y) (a.Z + b.Z)
    static member Zero         = Vector3.create 0.0 0.0 0.0
    static member DivideByInt(a,b) =
        Vector3.create
            (LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt a.X b)
            (LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt a.Y b)
            (LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt a.Z b)
```

then you can write

```
let xs = [1;2;3]
let ys = [Vector3.create 1.0 1.0 1.0; Vector3.create 1.0 1.0 1.0]

let inline sum xs =
    List.fold (fun a b -> a + b) LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero xs

let sumx = sum xs // int:     6
let sumy = sum ys // Vector3: 2.0 2.0 2.0
```

Comment: This is really interesting, so the automatic generalization is smart enough to understand DU cases! I *could* wrap my `'t` in an option, but this would incur a small run-time overhead later.

Comment: @sdgfsdh Is this really a overhead that breaks performance? Or just an assumption? Maybe `ValueOption` is better?

Comment: I think it depends on the use-case, which I didn't give since I only wanted a better understanding of F#. Suppose the type is numeric, then I could do `type Numeric<'t> = | Zero | NonZero of 't`, but any math operations would need to go through a `match`.

Comment: @sdgfsdh You can define a `Zero` member on your type, that is then used as Generic Zero.

Comment: I don't think that is possible for a `Vector3<'t>`